# How do I get a list of registered services in Autofac

Tags: autofac

In the **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**,I can:

```
        public static IServiceCollection BuildAopProxy(this IServiceCollection service)
        {
            foreach (ServiceDescriptor item in service)
            {}
        }
```

How do I get which registered components in Autofac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set of all registrations can be found in the `ComponentRegistry`, available in the container and any nested scopes:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<MyType>();

var container = builder.Build();

// Here is the list you want.
container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations;
```

If you actually want to resolve all providers of a specific service, you can just resolve an `IEnumerable<TService>`:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Two implementations of the same service.
builder.RegisterType<MyTypeA>().As<IService1>();
builder.RegisterType<MyTypeB>().As<IService1>();

var container = builder.Build();

// This will return a set with 2 items.
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IService1>>();
```